# Angular material mat-tree to show matInput on double click so I can edit in place

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I want to build a edit in place in [mat-tree component](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples#tree-checklist) where I could simply double click the tree element and edit the value.

I have added the double click method in element but when double click, it activate all tree matInput. I only want specific to edit. I have wrapped it inisde `ng container` element so it has its own scope but some reason its not working.

```
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle matTreeNodePadding>
    <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>


                  <ng-container>
                    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" *ngIf="nodeEdit; else nodeShow">
                      <input type="text" matInput value="{{node.item}}">                           
                    </mat-form-field>
                    <ng-template #nodeShow> <span (dblclick)='nodeEdit = !nodeEdit'>{{node.item}} (double click)</span></ng-template>
                  </ng-container>


  </mat-tree-node>

  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasNoContent" matTreeNodePadding>
    <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>New item...</mat-label>
      <input matInput #itemValue placeholder="Ex. Lettuce">
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-button (click)="saveNode(node, itemValue.value)">Save</button>
  </mat-tree-node>

  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild" matTreeNodePadding>
    <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle
            [attr.aria-label]="'Toggle ' + node.item">
      <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
        {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
      </mat-icon>
    </button>
    {{node.item}}   222
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="addNewItem(node)"><mat-icon>add</mat-icon></button>
  </mat-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

It shows output
[image]

But when double click on the one item it shows all input.

[image]

How can I make nodeEdit as local scope variable so only one input is active at a time.

Answer (score 0):

For now I used the existing checkbox toggle function. It worked as expected.

```
<ng-container>
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill" *ngIf="checklistSelection.isSelected(node)">
    <input type="text" matInput value="{{node.item}}">   
    <input type="button" value="Cancel" (click)="todoLeafItemSelectionToggle(node)">                        
  </mat-form-field>
  <span *ngIf="!checklistSelection.isSelected(node)" (dblclick)='todoLeafItemSelectionToggle(node)'>{{node.item}} (double click)</span>
</ng-container>
```

[image]